# Joining three tables without losing unmatched data

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables that I want to join. Example tables are shown below.

A:

| ID | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 23 |
| 4 | 24 |

B:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Sarah |
| 3 | Roger |

C:

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AA |
| 1 | BB |
| 2 | BB |
| 2 | CC |

I want the output to be table ABC, where ID 4 is gone because no name and Code CC is filtered out.

ABC:

| ID | Age | Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | John | AA |
| 1 | 21 | John | BB |
| 2 | 22 | Sarah | BB |
| 3 | 23 | Roger |  |

But what I get doesn't include ID 3 because Table C doesn't have ID 3.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,A.Age,B.Name,C.Code
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.ID=B.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID,Code
   FROM C WHERE CODE in ('AA','BB'))
ON A.ID=C.ID
```

Comment: Which Database you are using ?

Comment: Google cloud platform

Comment: Well, The below query shall word with `Google Cloud SQL` or any DBMS which supports your above query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it [as in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iPBpiDfj) in normal sql syntax using `LEFT JOIN` (For not to lose unmatched data) And [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, A.Age, B.Name, COALESCE(C.Code, '') AS Code
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ID AND C.Code IN ('AA', 'BB');
```

Output :

| ID | Age | Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | John | AA |
| 1 | 21 | John | BB |
| 2 | 22 | Sarah | BB |
| 3 | 23 | Roger |  |